# Method annotated with @KafkaListener not called if there are no messages

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka and the method annotated with `@KafkaListener` is not called if the `consumer.poll()` method does not return any message. Is it possible to enforce the calling of a method even if `consumer.poll()` returns an empty list of messages using `@KafkaListener`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can set the `idleEventInterval` on the listener container factory and then consume `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`s; the event is emitted if a poll returns no records have been received during that interval.

Consume the events by implementing `ApplicationListener<ListenerContainerIdleEvent>` or using an `@EventListener` method that receives a `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`.

Comment: I think with the `ConsumerRecords` method argument and `factory.setBatchListener(true)` we really can receive even empty `ConsumerRecords`. See `wantsFullRecords` logic in the `KafkaMessageListenerContainer.ListenerConsumer`

Comment: That is correct, but only in that case (or any batch listener, I guess), but it would have to be an option because it's a behavior change; we currently never invoke the listener if there are no records.

Comment: Ah! I see. It isn't going to work. We have a logic before like: `if (records != null && records.count() > 0) {`. Should we improve it somehow? At least for `wantsFullRecords` case...

Comment: Yes, I think we should consider it (for all batch listeners) but I think it has to be a new option (which can be true by default in 2.3). https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/939

Comment: I think it will be a good edition. For eg: may be there might be  a logic that is very specific in that class that wants to handle this scenario. Now in that listener I need to somehow get reference to that object, in this case may be use ThreadLocal now to get reference to that object in case we have multiple instances of same consumer.

Comment: So right now it seems like there is no option other than ListenerContainerIdleEvents to get the empty ConsumerRecords as well right?

Comment: Why do you feel the idle event does not provide what you need? I don't understand your comment about multiple instances of the **same** consumer. Each consumer instance is unique. There is no need for a ThreadLocal. Each consumer will publish its own idle events.

Comment: i guess I can inject the instance that listens to the messages in the class that will listen to the IdleEvent and perform what ever I want to

Comment: Or you can simply add `@EventListener public void containerIdle(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) { ... }` to a method in the same class as the `@KafkaListener` -

Comment: that makes more sense :)